# How AC circuit "Knows" how to divide the voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Let's say we have an AC circuit with EMF source of $12V$ and a resistor of $3 \Omega$ . Then a voltage of $12V$ falls on the resistor. Now if we add another resistor of $3 \Omega$ , the circuit "knows" to drop only $6V$ on each resistor.

I heard the fluid in pipes analogy but i'm looking for an electrodynamic explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my explanation, I will assume a DC circuit to have defined polarities to talk about. For an AC current, the explanation will hold true in any small time intervall where the voltage is nearly constant.

So we have a conductor on the potential 0V, which is connected to two resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$ of the same resistance in series and on the far side of $R_2$ the potential is 12V. Let's assume the conductor between $R_1$ and $R_2$ was on the potential 7V (or any other voltage $U$ with 6V $<U \leq $ 12V), so the voltage drops by 5V on $R_1$ and by 7V on $R_2$. This means, that the current through $R_2$ is higher and more electrons flow through it than through $R_1$, meaning that negative charges accumulate in the conductur between the two resistors. As a consequence, it's potential drops until it reaches the equilibrium point of 6V.